# Transposing and unstacking

Tags: awk

I am trying to transpose and unstack a huge text database (tab delimited).

My data looks something like this:

```
rs1 5   AB
rs2 5   BB
rs3 5   AA
rs1 6   BB
rs2 6   AA
rs3 6   AB
rs1 7   AA
rs2 7   AB
rs3 7   BB
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
    rs1 rs2 rs3

5   AB  BB  AA
6   BB  AA  AB
7   AA  AB  BB
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Luca

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with gawk. Looks painful, I am sure there are better ways of doing this but FWIW

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"}; 
{arr[$1, $2] = $3; arr1[$1]; arr2[$2]};
END{
for(x in arr1){printf " "x;} {print ""};
for(y in arr2){printf y" ";for(x in arr1) printf " "arr[x, y]; print ""}
   }' input_file
```